# Derived type inferred as any

Tags: typescript

Here, I want to be able to infer api as `{ login: (param: number) => Promise<void> }`, but I'm getting any.

```
export function createSlice<
  T extends Record<
    keyof T,
    (state: S, payload?: any) => S | ((api: {
      [K in keyof T]: Parameters<T[K]>[1] extends undefined
        ? { (): void }
        : { (payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]): void }
    }) => Promise<void>)
  >,
  N extends string,
  S,
>(
  config: T, name: N, initialState: S
) {
  return {};
}

interface TestState {
  isTest: boolean;
}

const slice = createSlice({
  login: (state: TestState, param: number) => async (api) => {
    api.login('sdf');
  },
}, 'testSlice', { isTest: false });
```

Is this a fundamental limitation? If so, how can I re-work the API to achieve what I want?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAGUAbTNYAHgFgAoOOAFTlBJQBMBnOAJWBpoXek2ZwA1sACeEBKwA0jCXAAUPGMWAAuOKUVwwhGeQiEuAfj2EUMgJRwAvAD59cAD7q1hMJj0A3iqqcADaANJwmLjScgosALp6AAqEUIQAtsAkUDw0LBEJLqEAjAnsIJy8cKhcwAjRwFzBIXCWcAHq9noAbhCYXHAAvi0hgerGpuZcKWmZ2cC5%20YXFZd1wfQPDo0OOrnDJUBAZmDy0m1wu9sEuyuIAchVVfJpQ0QDmd8wGjC5qwcIUA13noWIYUPM9PdDNFMFhCORSFoSHpSIxHEFxAQYEgoLgAkMANyMEYMRjRHIIQjUVjATRI7QdYKnFh0mB6ABGEAg5CIKGJDFJjEBmjgPEoNKceAI2goVGAakxzDM72ieg0yN0tPpmsMxnSGT0KCQGQ5iz2bkIPBk6HUvkwFqZ4mY9oAdCromoAOQ8LgIL32AXMIZ3ENwL0kekS4BewydFlsvRU8hnYaBoA)

Comment: there's no `ctx` in the code you posted

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: So there's no way to get the inference you want here without some manual annotation somewhere else, as far as I can tell.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzeJQm) meet your needs or address the question? If so I could maybe write up an answer, although I see that you've been re-asking this question multiple times and I can't tell if that's because you didn't like what I already said about this before (and/or that I failed to write up an answer in a timely enough manner for your purposes) or if there's some other reason.  Let me know (I won't get notified unless you say @jcalz).

Comment: @jcalz The only problem with this solution is that it [doesn't account for optional parameters. If you change the annotation to `{ login: number | undefined }` then it still errors with `api.login()`

Comment: For instance here https://tsplay.dev/NdYeMm
`loginSuccess()` is expecting an argument. But without the `login` definition, it works.

Comment: @jcalz I've made one small change to your example to get this to work (second `T[K]` should be `T[P]`): https://tsplay.dev/w8L8Mw

If you would like to write it up, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Oh oops yeah that was a typo.  Okay I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all I've seen it isn't generally possible to get the sort of simultaneous inference of both [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters and of callback parameter types from [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).  While it might be easy enough for a human being to intuit the right order in which such inference would have to happen to be successful (in your case, infer the `T` type parameter from the keys and second parameters of the methods in the `config` argument, and then infer the parameters for callbacks returned from these methods), the compiler isn't really able to do this.  It has an algorithm that works well in a lot of cases, but fails in other cases.  There are various issues in GitHub about this sort of thing; for example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#44999](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999).  Mostly these are closed as design limitations, with a link back to [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), a suggestion to implement a *full unification algorithm* that will probably stay an unimplemented suggestion for a long time (or forever) because it would be a huge undertaking without an obviously high chance of improvement.

For now, this means that you will need to cut the Gordian knot either by manually annotating a callback parameter you would prefer not to annotate, or by manually specifying a generic type parameter you would prefer not to specify.  I think the latter is probably the better approach, especially if we refactor so that the type you specify is as terse as possible.  Here's one approach:

```
declare const createSlice: <T extends object>() =>
  <N extends string, S>(
    config: { [K in keyof T]:
      (state: S, payload: T[K]) => S | (
        (api: { [P in keyof T]: (payload: T[P]) => void }) => Promise<void>
      ) },
    name: N,
    initialState: S
  ) => void;
```

This is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function that works around the lack of *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  We're going to have to specify `T` manually, but we'd still like the compiler to infer `N` and `S`.  That can't be done in a single generic function, so I've split it up so that you can specify `T` and then the returned function will infer `N` and `S` for you.  It is what it is.

I've also refactored `T` so that it is just a mapping from key to the second method parameter type directly.  This type looks like the relatively simple `{login: number}` and not the more complex `{login: (s: S, p: number) => S | ...` corresponding to the `config` parameter.  Instead we start with the simpler `T` and [map it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to the type of `config`.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const slice = createSlice<{
  login: number,
  loginSuccess: void,
}>()({
  loginSuccess: (state) => state,
  login: (state, param) => async (api) => {
    api.login(123); // <--  okay
    api.login('sdf'); // <-- error
    api.loginSuccess(); // <-- okay
  },
}, 'testSlice', { isTest: false });
```

Looks good.  The result of `createSlice<{login: number, loginSuccess: void}>()` is of type

```
<N extends string, S>(config: {
    login: (state: S, payload: number) => S | ((api: {
        login: (payload: number) => void;
        loginSuccess: (payload: void) => void;
    }) => Promise<void>);
    loginSuccess: (state: S, payload: void) => S | ((api: {
        login: (payload: number) => void;
        loginSuccess: (payload: void) => void;
    }) => Promise<void>);
}, name: N, initialState: S) => void
```

And when you call that with the above parameters, the compiler can easily infer that `N` is of type `"testSlice"`, that `S` is of type `{isTest: boolean}`, and that the unannotated `api` callback parameter is of type `{login: (payload: number)=>void; loginSuccess: (payload: void) => void}`.

That's about as close as I can think of to what you want here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0XKGQGUIBLMEALngB4AVeEADzxWDXiQCMArcDAPgAoAlPAC8vALAAoeFQBydRiGatMMIigDmAGnj4BUmTOQoAZkQ0UA3vADaAaXjr4AaxABPJCfjUAumQOGMvyYuOS6OgAOUG4QSFDAFNT2PsJiuvAAPvD8AYFBUBFEVrYACo4oLu6e3n7ZUTFxCd42JSmivPAAbkhEwPAAvqkdJTBIALZEaCCU3b0S0nnC-Vq58ChQY2GyKwsy6kQYRFAQ+BihFPgBQ109wADcUo+S6ngwJlCk3iCYp6HwlgFJtRvhgKOwkEgICAoCgHpJ+k9jJh4GhiJ8RNhoXhCCRpgCFrENOoKCgAK5jdggGA7GSE9T4UlgUhoNAUWbAHb9ASCfj42lIIkoBlM76s7IhPDXCUgGnwOkoCjBM54SKwDbXKBoNwoMDZApEa58wz6gB08v4AEYAEwAZkEd3gAHpHVQALSumRIZzRVam80AcjQwBM-vtTpdlHddBgoxgvsKZoF9MZzLQQgdzrdHq9PoWyyky3g-rwPzRIH9OmsQJBFHeECmA3tTykSKwLypm2ARzw1AAFuoNKJMaEcaRKEb5STyZTqQF5cLU2zbpzuXDHQAqRCoZHtmCd7sgPsDiiUeQMJgsFEYNSaHR6fjGMwWf6rSfi5VhfCqhrxKcUqnXPgmTZPw+pWKsgRvvw9SxL+azTgB7Q3L0cJ5IY84pqKiowY0S69Nc7KoYYgxISM4yTNM7K8E2uxykmQqYSyirShc36wU07KAcB-CgYU4G0ZB9HYdE7F-jOBG3ERaEYSKTF1CJuHIcAEkoasJFpGRExTDMtzUXChbrJsFDbOUBxHCcH4XCpfTro6iLblgqK4laQ67vuoRHpovJzvRC5Ye+oRSh+spQdKqowOqSGatquq8QaSFGjIfr0ZatphpmkYemw3puPGRCJoK-CBsGoYZhGUZUrGeUFcmslpul5XZjlAT5vCOjFiCo7lpWjhoMCmC1scDaDGuLqtuUrzuT2-aaCeABEJYYF1c09dWA3wOCkLQrCAzckAA)